# What program to open these AMF files?

Tags: extract, open

I have these 3 AMF files and wondering what program should i use to open or extract it?

here is the file location

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cxg0kOsaDQZWJURDB6NU1WWWM/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cxg0kOsaDQamdnbUdNZHhRQlU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Behind the *two* zlib layers, the files have several mentions of "fv2" and various terms from the Farmville game, e.g. `fv2_rabbitwarren_minigame` or `averageFarmbucksPurchased`

So I would have guessed [Action Message Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format), an IPC format that [Farmville](http://nettech.wikia.com/wiki/Farmville) uses. However, I can't get any AMF parser to work with them...

Either way, the files don't have interesting data – not control messages but rather something that looks like parts of a program's structure (lots and *lots* of function names, object names).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, they are from those game and they are parts of the game. It is the file where they store information or values. How do you view it? i mean to view the object names, function names (that is what i need to view) . What program did you use? 

I have a website about this games and i write news and updates by getting information from these files. Before they use a json file (which i can ope with a json editor), now they change it to AMF. I don't have any programming knowledge.